# Could not find a simulator that matches 'simulator' (RuntimeError)

Tags: ios, cucumber, ios-simulator, calabash

Running into an odd error when running my Cucumber tests through Calabash on an ios simulator (iPhone5 os=8).  My steps are all passing but the scenario ultimately fails.  I've looked for hanging expectations and could not come up with any culprits.  The Scenario works through its steps in the simulator correctly and executes all the commands appropriately, yet the scenario fails. When I run the Scenario with --format pretty I get this

```
Could not find a simulator that matches 'simulator' (RuntimeError)
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.11.3/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:267:in `reset_app_sandbox'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.11.3/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:565:in `relaunch'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.11.3/lib/calabash-cucumber/core.rb:838:in `start_test_server_in_background'
```

~/features/media_mobile/helpers/ios/support/app_life_cycle_hooks.rb:43:in `Before'

```
  Could not find a simulator that matches 'simulator' (RuntimeError)
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.11.3/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:267:in `reset_app_sandbox'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.11.3/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:565:in `relaunch'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.11.3/lib/calabash-cucumber/core.rb:838:in `start_test_server_in_background'
```

~/features/media_mobile/helpers/ios/support/app_life_cycle_hooks.rb:43:in `Before'

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber -p ios features/login1.feature:26 # Scenario: Login

1 scenario (1 failed)
9 steps (9 passed)

Not certain what is going on.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this command specifying the simulator

```
PLATFORM=iphone DEVICE_TARGET='iPhone 5s (7.1 Simulator)' APP_BUNDLE_PATH=users/.../build/Staging-iphonesimulator/your_app-cal.app cucumber -v --format html --out iphone.html $DIR_PATH/features/*.feature
```

Specify ios version and APP Bundle path according to your needs skip App bundle path if you use the default derived data folder.

Comment: While your solution was not quite what I needed it definitely pointed me down the right path. I was brought on to fix/finish the code of a previous employee who is no longer with the company.  And while I had glanced at the cucumber.yml he had written I had not really started to poke around until your suggestion of specifying the simulator.  I tried a few different things but what fixed it was moving "RESET_BETWEEN_SCENARIOS", which he had placed after the Target definitions, to the beginning of the string.  Tests and Scenarios are now passing.  Thanks!